# How to merge two dataframes and keep only different columns (content)?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frame with same row size and different column number, the name of the columns is also different, however the content may be similar in some of them.

i.e. df1:

```
df1<- data.frame("a"=c("0","1","0","1","0","0","0"),
                "b"=c("1","1","1","1","1","0","0"),
                "c"=c("1","1","0","0","1","0","0"),
                "d"=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1"))
```

df2:

```
df2<- data.frame("e"=c("1","1","0","1","0","0","0"),
                "f"=c("1","1","1","1","1","0","0"),
                "g"=c("0","0","0","0","1","0","0"),
                "h"=c("0","0","0","0","1","1","1"))
```

If you see, the column "b" of df1 and "f" of df2 are equal. Therefore, the result I want is a new dataframe looking like this:

```
df3 <- data.frame("a"=c("0","1","0","1","0","0","0"),
                  "c"=c("1","1","0","0","1","0","0"),
                  "d"=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1"),
                  "e"=c("1","1","0","1","0","0","0"),
                  "g"=c("0","0","0","0","1","0","0"),
                  "h"=c("0","0","0","0","1","1","1"))
```

NOTE: column "b" and "f" (that were similar) are not in the new df3.
I have looked in the web but I did not find an example for this. I think the major complexity is that the merge is by content and not by column name.

Comment: could you not merge then remove them by using `df3[, -c(2, 3)]`, the numbers in the brackets suggest which columns to remove. Although, you may want an all-in-one function for your suggestion?

Comment: Hi Lime, the problem is that my data frames are bigger than this simplified example (around 2000 rows by 10000 columns df1, and 2000 rows time 100 columns df2). So I cannot identify visually which columns are similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the job:

```
df3 <- cbind(df1,df2)
df3 <- t(t(df3)[!(duplicated(t(df3)) | duplicated(t(df3), fromLast = TRUE)),])
df3

#  a c d e g h
#1 0 1 1 1 0 0
#2 1 1 1 1 0 0
#3 0 0 1 0 0 0
#4 1 0 1 1 0 0
#5 0 1 1 0 1 1
#6 0 0 1 0 0 1
#7 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

this will give you a `matrix`, you can save the result as a `df` if so desired

Comment: I tied and it works fine. If there are duplicated columns in the df1, it also removes them. Thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to check for the columns that perfectly match.

```
mat <- sapply(df1, function(x) sapply(df2, function(y) all(x == y)))
mat

#      a     b     c     d
#e FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#f FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#g FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#h FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Here we can see column `b` from `df1` and column `f` from `df2` should be removed. We can do this by :

```
m2 <- which(mat, arr.ind = TRUE)
cbind(df1[-m2[, 2]], df2[-m2[, 1]])

#  a c d e g h
#1 0 1 1 1 0 0
#2 1 1 1 1 0 0
#3 0 0 1 0 0 0
#4 1 0 1 1 0 0
#5 0 1 1 0 1 1
#6 0 0 1 0 0 1
#7 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ronak, I am trying with this. However, I have dataframes with dimensions  2000 x 10000 and 2000 x 100 and it is taken a long time to run.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer` from `base R`

```
mat <- outer(df1, df2, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x == y)))
mat
#      e     f     g     h
#a FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#b FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#c FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#d FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now, we can get the row/column names

```
m2 <- as.matrix(subset(as.data.frame.table(mat), Freq, select = -Freq))
```

Now, we use the 'm2' to get remove the column names from 'df1', 'df2' and `cbind`

```
cbind(df1[setdiff(names(df1), m2[,1])], df2[setdiff(names(df2), m2[,2])])
#  a c d e g h
#1 0 1 1 1 0 0
#2 1 1 1 1 0 0
#3 0 0 1 0 0 0
#4 1 0 1 1 0 0
#5 0 1 1 0 1 1
#6 0 0 1 0 0 1
#7 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: I think it works fine with small dataset. However in my case I could use it because it take too much memory. Thank you anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# based on Ronak's sapply approach
matches <- as.data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x) sapply(df2, function(y) identical(x, y)))) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "df2") %>%
  pivot_longer(-df2, names_to = "df1") %>% # pivot longer
  filter(value) # keep only the matches

# programmatically build list of names to remove
vars_remove <- c(matches$df1, matches$df2) # will remove var names that are matches
df1 %>% bind_cols(df2) %>%
  select(-any_of(vars_remove))

  a c d e g h
1 0 1 1 1 0 0
2 1 1 1 1 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0 0
4 1 0 1 1 0 0
5 0 1 1 0 1 1
6 0 0 1 0 0 1
7 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It is also an useful approach.